# Intersection of Sigma Algebra with a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to Show:

> If $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$ and $Y\subset X$. Then
>   show that $\mathscr{H}=\{E\cap Y|E\in \mathscr{A}\}$ is also $\sigma$
>   algebra.

I have difficulty in proving that if $J\in \mathscr{H}\implies J^c\in \mathscr{H}$.

Can anyone please provide me hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complement should be done relative to $Y$, because $\mathscr{H}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

So, given $J\in\mathscr{H}$, say $J=E\cap Y$ for $E\in\mathscr{A}$, we have that

$$
Y\setminus J=Y\setminus (E\cap Y)=Y\cap (X\setminus E)
$$

Comment: Rather, I would say *if* $\mathscr H$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, *then* it would be a $\sigma$-algebra over $Y$ *because* $Y\cap X$ is the largest set in $\mathscr H$.